# How to disable/prevent standard user from accessing the appearance setting in 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, appearance

I have 50 plus PC running with Ubuntu 14.04 and I am planning to upgrade it to 16.04. How can I disable or prevent standard user from accessing or changing the wallpaper, icons, etc..

Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

First of: why? They can't do any harm with it and you might think it is easy but you are forgetting a couple of things.

You do it like this ...

```
sudo chmod 700 /usr/bin/unity-control-center
```

This will prevent users to change any settings provided by the graphical interface but ... this will not prevent them from using command-line or a TTY. If they know how to use `gsettings` they can still alter any of these options. So you probably also want to prevent them from using `gsettings`. And a can of worms opens :)

Now for a better method:

Why not reset these settings you do not want them to alter on every boot? Just create a script with the `gsettings` in  it.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///dir/dir/dir/wallpaper.png
```

will change the wallpaper. Similar to that you can create lines for other options. Execute the script somewhere, and make the script non-mutable for normal users. This works if you only want a few settings.

If you really want to reset all settings: create a script to read all current settings and reload those settings when the system is booted.

--

Easier method:

```
cd ~/.config/dconf/ 
~/.config/dconf$ ls  
user
~/.config/dconf$ file user
user: GVariant Database file, version 0
```

... copy this file and restore it during a boot.

Comment: Interesting approach, I thought of recommending moving the `settings.desktop` file to `/root/.local/share/applications/` but then again there is still the settings menu entry in the user menu and then the terminal as well, like you said a whole can of worms.

Comment: thank you Rinzwind when i try to run sudo chmod 700 /usr/bin/gnome-control-center 
it give me a answer of no such file or directory

Comment: @Angelo4501 found an easier method ;-) Regarding comment: bug spotted... it is now `unity-control-center`.

Comment: about the gsettings i've already try it but i want all appearance setting will not change...i mean i used that command and it returns to the set wallpaper but the icon size the color they can change it. i there any way or script where i can set icon size,color,and wallpaper as my customize setting as a default whether they change it and when reboot it will back to my customize setting?

Comment: @Rinzwind i will try it ^_^

Comment: same issue @Rinzwind no such file